# Dimensions of list used in test

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I would like to reduce the number of brackets in a list for nested lists containing 1 sublist. For instance `{{1,2,3}}` should become `{1,2,3}`

However, `{{1,2,3},{4,5}}` should stay the same.

I used:

```
DropLevel[x_] := Level[x, {-1}] /; Dimensions[x][[1]] == 1
```

Which gives an error on `{{1,2,3},{4,5}}` but works on  `{{1,2,3}}`

`Dimensions[x][[1]]==1` does work as a test for checking whether a list has two sublists or only 1.

Am I missing something about the way  `/;` functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ReplaceAll` with the replacement rule `{{x__}} :> {x}`:

```
stripDoubleBraces = # /. {{x__}} :> {x} &

stripDoubleBraces @ {{1, 2, 3}}
```

> {1, 2, 3}

```
stripDoubleBraces @ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}
```

> {{1, 2, 3},{4,5}}

If you need to the stripping work with arbitrarily deep nesting, you can replace `ReplaceAll` with `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
 {{1}, {{{{{{{5}}}}}}}} //. {{x__}} :> {x}
```

> {{1}, {5}}

Comment: Thanks again! I will dig into that book soon. Pattern matching is so cool in this language.